# Python read excel cell with date formula

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I need to run a python script every day to read the cell value in excel workbook and find the file path. The `cell(4,1)` is like `="XXXXXX_"&TODAY()&".xlsx"`

```
configSheet=xlrd.open_workbook(configFile).sheet_by_name("Config")

reportFile = configSheet.cell_value(4,1)
```

next day, the system date change, when run the script, it is still getting previous date value. How can I make the cell update `today()` value when reading the excel?

Comment: I'm not sure but I guess you have to open Excel that today is executed and save the new result. Therefore I would Lauch the execl sheet from python wait for some seconds save and close

Comment: If you just want a file path with today's date in it, can you just build it yourself by doing `'XXXXXX_{}.xlsx'.format(datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))` (adjust formatting as desired to match Excel)?

Comment: I did something like: filepath+datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%‌​m-%d') as walkaround,but the file path is extremely long and contain complicated dates (today/yesterday/this month), better separate the variable from the code. also, when user open the config excel, he can see what the path is, and make change in the cell if the path change.